# RecyclerView jumps to the top when paginating

Tags: java, android, pagination, android-recyclerview

Trying to implement pagination in RecyclerView, but when the RecyclerView reaches it's end and applications starts loading new portion of data the RecyclerView jumps to it's top.

```
cityListRecyclerview = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    cityListRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    loadFromUrl();

    cityListRecyclerview.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            visibleItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getChildCount();
            totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            pastVisiblesItems = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

            if (loading) {
                if ( (visibleItemCount+pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                    loading = false;
                    page++;
                    url += Api.OFFSET_URL + String.valueOf(page);
                    loadFromUrl();
                    Log.v("LIST", "Last Item Wow !");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

The loadFromUrl() method:

```
public void loadFromUrl() {

    Ion.with(MainActivity.this)
            .load(url)
            .asJsonObject()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject jsonObject) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("flats");

                    jsonObjectToPass = jsonArray;

                    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
                        JsonElement obj = jsonArray.get(i);
                        JsonObject jsonObject1 = obj.getAsJsonObject();
                       ............ here parsing JSON object and nothing interesting
                        adapter = new OffersAdapter(MainActivity.this, cityList);
                        adapter.setClickListener(MainActivity.this);
                        loading = true;
                        cityListRecyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }

                }

            });

}
```

The XML file:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

And the gradle file:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'}
```

So can anyone tell what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the problem was really stupid! First i moved this two things into onCreate()

```
adapter = new OffersAdapter(MainActivity.this, cityList);
cityListRecyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And added

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

In loadFromUrl() method, and now everything works well :D Maybe if someone will have the same problem, then he'll see my post :D

Comment: Am using the same but again the recycler view move to top.

Comment: @RAHULRSANNIDHI are you fully reloading your `RecyclerView`? Because this solution works when you need to reload it completely.

Comment: Was doing same mistake. Works for me!